# What causes this error..please run "exec sp_register_custom_scripting 'CUSTOM_SCRIPT', your_script?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, replication, ddl

Configuration

SQL 2005 (Server A) replicates to SQL 2008(Server B) which replicates to SQL 2008(Server C).

I recently added a column (to Server A) to a replicated table via script & the DDL change replicated to Server B with out a problem.  When the DDL change replicated to Server C, I received the error below.

**'DDL replication failed to refresh custom procedures, please run "exec sp_register_custom_scripting 'CUSTOM_SCRIPT', your_script, 'EDI from xx', 'table_name_here' "and try again (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 21814)'**

These subscriptions (on Server B to Server C) were created via a script below.

**exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'EDI to XLOCX', @subscriber = N'RXLOCXS-SQLA', @destination_db = N'EDI', @subscription_type = N'Push', @sync_type = N'replication support only', @article = N'all', @update_mode = N'read only', @subscriber_type = 0

exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'EDI to XLOCX (Merge)', @subscriber = N'RXLOCXS-SQLA', @subscriber_db = N'EDI', @job_login = N'ROUSES.COM\RXLOCXSQLREPL', @job_password = N'XPASSWORDX', @subscriber_security_mode = 1, @frequency_type = 4, @frequency_interval = 1, @frequency_relative_interval = 1, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 1, @frequency_subday = 8, @frequency_subday_interval = 1, @active_start_time_of_day =3300, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 20070923, @active_end_date = 99991231, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', @dts_package_location = N'Distributor'**

GO

So the million dollar question is, why do I get the error 'exec sp_register_custom_scripting 'CUSTOM_SCRIPT', your_script' when I add a column to a table in the EDI to XLOCX publication???

AHIA,

LarryR...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a custom stored procedure (SP) is used to replicate the data.  The custom SP needs to be updated to reflect the column change.  The SP needs to be updated on all servers.  The information about custom procedures will be associated with the article and not the subscription.

If you're not using, the you'll need to determine why the article thinks it needs a custom procedure.